# The IMAP server replied to the 'NAMESPACE' command with a 'BAD' response: User is authenticated but not connected

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, imap, mailkit

I am trying to connect into `Outlook` mailbox, fetching, extracting data from mails and working with them in `DataGrid`. My problem is, that after few seconds(around 30seconds) my app gets freeze and will show this exception

> The IMAP server replied to the 'NAMESPACE' command with a 'BAD'
> response: User is authenticated but not connected.
> I have read here in stackoverflow, that this is caused by more loggins, that Microsoft allows(more than 20, I think).

My Question is: How to fix it?
My app is in development, so I didn't think for `OAUTH2.0 verification`. But could be this the solution?

Thanks for any advice.

This is how I am using Mailkit library

```
public static void MailKitLib(EmailParser emailParser)
        {

            bool help = true;

            do
            {

                using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                using (var cancel = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource())
                {
                       
                    client.Connect(emailParser.ServerName, emailParser.Port, emailParser.IsSSLuse,
                        cancel.Token);

                    client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);

                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);


                    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                        Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                        if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                        {
                            dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                            Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                            if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                            {
                                dAOAlert.Save(alert);

                            }
                          
                        }

                    }

                        //client.Disconnect(true, cancel.Token);
                    }
                }

        } while (help != false);

        }
```

Comment: Not sure if its any help in your case, but I got this error when I was trying to authenticate through a browser that apparently sat on some old cookie or something.  I got the OAuth token from MS but it didn't work.  Trying to authenticate from an incognito browser started the whole MS Authenticator rigamarole (which also didn't work, but in a different way).

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird state that Exchange gets into. Search StackOverflow for similar questions. I know it's been answered before (even if not for MailKit specifically).

The error means that you used the correct username and password but your user account does not have access permissions to email over the IMAP protocol.